# JavaScript: Overlay function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit new to javascript and Jquery so I really have very little Idea about what I'm doing. I've managed to wing it for most of this, with a little bit of trial and error. I'm not sure if there are any alternatives to javascript that might be better. I know users can turn off javascript which could be an issue with this script once I get it working but I really don't want to use PHP/Sever-side stuff if possible.

This is the bit I'm having issue with, I'm not getting any errors in the console and the script runs all the way through but this first bit is not working.

I have both a .hidden and .visible CSS classes and an ID in a div right after html because this is the only way It will overlay everything on the screen.

It's late so I may not respond till tomorrow.

```
    $(function() {
        var loading = function() {
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay .hidden')

        overlay.onclick = function() {
            overlay.setAttribute('class', 'visible');
};
};
loading()
});
```

This is the whole script.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
$('a[href^="http://"],a[href^="https://"]')
    .not('[href*="localhost"]')
    .click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var goTo = this.getAttribute("href");

    $(function() {
        var loading = function() {
        var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay .hidden')

        overlay.onclick = function() {
            overlay.setAttribute('class', 'visible');
};
};
loading()
});

    setTimeout(function(){

         window.location = goTo;
    },7000);       
});
});
```

HTML bit

```
<html lang="en">
<div id="overlay .hidden" class="overlay"></div>
 <head>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
        display: none;
}
.visible {
        display: block;
   }

#overlay {
  display: inline;
  z-index: 99999999999;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: can you post your html too to clear the spec?

Comment: If you need more let me know. I think this is the only part that should matter to the script.

Comment: Are you sure using and id="overlay .hidden" is a good idea? The css selector for #overlay may not be selecting the div.

Comment: Changing this to overlay would make the entire page black, but after further review you're correct. It does keep the CSS from working.

Comment: use jquery like 

$("you event selector").click(function(){

$(".overlay").toggle();

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was missing a ajax libs href code in my sources so I added it into my header. I also added back in my original code that was working. Due to me using the ajax source code it wasn't acknowledging the overlay as part of the script.

Thanks to all the people that replied, even though it didn't help specifically In this situation I learned a lot.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
$('a[href^="http://"],a[href^="https://"]')
    .not('[href*="localhost"]')
    .click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor behavior
    var goTo = this.getAttribute("href");

    $(function() {

    var loading = function() {
        // add the overlay with loading image to the page
        var over = '<div id="overlay">' +
            '<img id="loading" src="">' +
            '<a style="color:white; text-align:center"> This is test </a>'+
            '</div>';
        $(over).prependTo('body');
    };
    loading()
    });
    setTimeout(function(){

         window.location = goTo;
    },7000);       
});
});
```